# LVM : lvextend on striped volume

Tags: linux, partitioning, lvm, stripe

This is my first question in "stack"-systems and... it's probably very silly.

Especially because I **think** I know the answer, but as it's about some production system with critical data, I'd like to be sure and have a little confirmation.

So, the situation.

We have a storage server which is connected to storage array (it's a DDN storage array composed with principal unit and an extension). The data volume on the server is a LVM volume.

Actually it's based on 6 physical volumes.

I was a little bit surprised when I discover that it has some strange stripe configuration :

```
[root ~]# lvs --segments
  LV          VG         Attr     #Str Type    SSize
  data        ddn        -wi-ao--    4 striped 114.00t
  data        ddn        -wi-ao--    2 striped  57.11t
```

The volume was not created by me and I'm not sure about reasons for this configuration. May be there are two explanations :

a) initially the volume was created only with 4 PV; the 2 others were added later.

b) The first 4 PV are situated in the principal unit of storage array, and the 2 others are situated in the extension.

In any way, it works actually pretty well.

Now, I would like to add a new volume to my LVM.
I have only one volume to add and it's not possible to add two volumes.

I successfully did `pvcreate` and `vgextend`.

But, when I try to do

`lvextend /dev/ddn/data -l+100%FREE`

it asks me about stripes. I'm a little bit confused.

Should I indicate

```
lvextend /dev/ddn/data -l+100%FREE --stripes 3
```

to try to add my volume to the group of data

> ddn        -wi-ao--    2 striped  57.11t

or

```
lvextend /dev/ddn/data -l+100%FREE --stripes 1
```

because I have only one volume so it could be only striped by itself (no striped as I understand).

The second possibility seems to be correct. And the first one no (as we could not add a volume to already striped group, at least without some manipulations).

I read this article :
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/5/html/logical_volume_manager_administration/lv

Especially point *5.4.9. Extending a Striped Volume* and it seems to confirm my idea that I should do "--stripes 1", but I would like to be sure.

Another additional question. 
If the answer "stripes 1" is correct. In RedHat article they said :

> If you do not have enough underlying physical devices to extend the
>   striped logical volume, it is possible to extend the volume anyway if
>   it does not matter that the extension is not striped, which may result
>   in uneven performance.

Do you think it will really impact the performances?

The performance issue is important for us, but not critical.
So if it could impact performances a little and in some cases : it's acceptable for us.
But if it could really slowdown our system... I do not know that to do (as I said I could add only one PV, it's not possible to add another PV at the moment).

Thanks for your help. And sorry for silly question.